# jQuery Masonry Child selector without a class name

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, jquery-masonry

I have a problem with Masonry.

Here is where I need Masonry to be applied.

```
<ul class="text">
  <li> 
       <ul>
            <li> <!--Trying to apply masonry only  here-->
               <ul>
                  <li></li><!--Not here-->
               </ul>     
             </li>
            <li> <!--Trying to apply masonry only here-->
               <ul>
                  <li></li> <!--Not here-->
               </ul>     
             </li>
        </ul> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

Only apply masonry on the li tag of second ul. If I don't add a class to each of the li tag masonry won't work properly because it will also add it the next ul >li. I can get it to work if I add a class to each of li like this, but it is kinda complicated to do with php.

```
<ul class="text">
      <li> 
           <ul>
                <li class="class"> <!--Trying to apply masonry only  here-->
                   <ul>
                      <li></li><!--Not here-->
                   </ul>     
                 </li>
                <li class="class"> <!--Trying to apply masonry only here-->
                   <ul>
                      <li></li> <!--Not here-->
                   </ul>     
                 </li>
            </ul> 
       </li>
    </ul>
```

Using this:

```
   $("ul.text > li > ul").masonry({
                itemSelector : '.class'
            });
```

But I don't want to add a class. I tried something like but it keeps applying masonry to all li tags.

```
    $("ul.text> li > ul").masonry({
        itemSelector : 'li'
    });
```

Is there a way to this without applying a class?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a .masonry-brick Masonry applies its layout logic to it. If you have elements nested inside your .masonry-brick they will inevitably have Masonry's layout logic applied to them, too. Read the documentation again how Masonry works and look at sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Docs

> Filters item elements to selector. If not set, Masonry defaults to
>   using the child elements of the container.
>
> Recommended to avoid Masonry using any other hidden elements in its
>   layout logic.

So i think you should remove `itemSelector : 'li'` According on documentation it is correct

Comment: Oh this is weird, it worked! I tried this before and it didn't work but now it does. Maybe because I edited the css style. Well Thanks

Comment: Welcam)) if it helped you, please click accepted and rep for question)))

Answer (score 0):

try

```
itemselector : 'ul.text> li > ul > li'
```

Comment: Nope. Itemselector must be one element either a class, id or simply the element.